# .mov file, video not playing just audio

Tags: video

I have a `.mov` file that I am trying to run using VLC and totem movie player.

When I try running it with VLC I get audio but no video, and when I try running it using totem I get the following error message:

```
Internal GStreamer error: negotiation problem.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
```

When I go to the properties in totem movie player it mentions that the video codec for my video is Sorensen video v.3.

Answer (score 2):

It's often the file itself that is the problem, not Totem or VLC. Be sure you have encoded the file properly.

FFMpeg is great for encoding; encoding your file to a different format may solve the problem.

```
ffmpeg -i Test.mp4 -sameq -r 24 Test.mov
```

is usually the command I use.

[Here is a long list of options for encoding video/audio files.](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC18)

Answer (score 1):

MPlayer plays most MPEG, VOB, AVI, Ogg/OGM, VIVO, ASF/WMA/WMV, QT/MOV/MP4, FLI, RM, NuppelVideo, yuv4mpeg, FILM, RoQ, PVA files, supported by many native, XAnim, RealPlayer, and Win32 DLL codecs. It can also play VideoCD, SVCD, DVD, 3ivx, RealMedia, and DivX movies.

## [mplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mplayer) [image: Install mplayer]

and include [Medibuntu repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) and install :

*For i386, the package is called w32codecs:*

```
sudo apt-get install w32codecs
```

*For amd64, the package is called w64codecs:*

```
sudo apt-get install w64codecs
```

Comment: No still that didn't help, i still can't run the video!!

Answer (score 1):

UPS! You get a negotiation problem, so looks like you're having one of those weird codification problems that sometimes you get hit because of the not openness codification :D

When I have those problems, I run the [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm) (because is easier and more effective than WinFF). It uses mencoder.

(Cross platform).

Try that if you want and see if you can convert the file to avi or mp4 for instance.